# No handlers for address while using eventBus in communicating between verticles of a springboot project

Tags: vert.x

I developed a project with Springboot and used Vertx as an asynchronous reactive toolkit. My ServerVerticle, create a httpServer which receives http requests from an Angular app and sends messages to it via eventBus. By the way, the time that received message arrives, ServerVerticle sends it to another verticle which has service instance in it (for connecting to repository). i tested it with postman and get "No handlers for address" error as a bad request.
here is my ServerVerticle:

```java
HttpServerResponse res = routingContext.response();
res.setChunked(true);
EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();
eventBus.request(InstrumentsServiceVerticle.FETCH_INSTRUMENTS_ADDRESS, "", result -> {
    if (result.succeeded()) {
        res.setStatusCode(200).write((Buffer) result.result().body()).end();
    } else {
        res.setStatusCode(400).write(result.cause().toString()).end();
    }

});
```

My instrumentVerticle is as follows:

```java
static final String FETCH_INSTRUMENTS_ADDRESS = "fetch.instruments.service";
// Reuse the Vert.x Mapper :)
private final ObjectMapper mapper = Json.mapper;

private final InstrumentService instrumentService;

public InstrumentsServiceVerticle(InstrumentService instrumentService) {
    this.instrumentService = instrumentService;
}

private Handler<Message<String>> fetchInstrumentsHandler() {
    return msg -> vertx.<String>executeBlocking(future -> {
                try {
                    future.complete(mapper.writeValueAsString(instrumentService.getInstruments()));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    logger.error("Failed to serialize result "+ InstrumentsServiceVerticle.class.getName());
                    future.fail(e);
                }
            },
            result -> {
                if (result.succeeded()) {
                    msg.reply(result.result());
                } else {
                    msg.reply(result.cause().toString());
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    super.start();
    vertx.eventBus().<String>consumer(FETCH_INSTRUMENTS_ADDRESS).handler(fetchInstrumentsHandler());
}
```

and i deployed both verticles in the springbootApp starter.

Comment: how did you `deployed both verticles in the springbootApp starter`?

Comment: I found out that i had deployed it in a wrong way as i changed it to Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(serverVerticle); and it worked :)